# Azure windows server 2019 install docker

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, docker-machine

I hope somebody can help me with this issue.

I have a windows server 2019 hosted on azure. I would like to install docker for some tests.

Before to jump to docker, I updated the operative system

I downloaded docker desktop from docker website.

Installation went without any issue.

But when I try to start the app, I get the error that the Hyper-V is not running.

At this point, in the server management tool => add features I checked if `Hyper-v` was installed and if `containers` was also installed, After this I went to `services.msc` and restarted `Hyper-v managment` and also set to `auto` `hypervisorlaunchtype` and restarted the VM. When I logged in back, I had the same issue.

I know this is a case of nested virtualisation, but I was wondering if is achievable on a cloud platform.

Can please anyone help me to understand this and if its possible or/and what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to install the docker desktop in my environment and it was successful with out any issue. Created a vm with windows server 2019 and updated to latest and installed docker desktop from here [Install Docker Desktop on Windows](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/install/)  and it is running as expected.

[image]

Nested virtualizations is supported in azure but all the vm sizes not support nested virtualization, So Try to deploy the VM with any of the following series D_v3; Ds_v3; E_v3; Es_v3; F2s_v2 – F72s_v2; M and check.